# I want to extract URL contain in my Wordpress post

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have around 1K posts in my blog. Every post contain URL something like "www.example.com/abcd.html" or "www.example.com/1234.html".

I want to extract those URL from every posts into a file.

Is there any query to do this job done?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

```
 This will display all post link with title
 <?php  query_posts('posts_per_page=-1'); ?>
 <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
 <?php 
 $content = $urls = wp_extract_urls( get_the_content() );
 echo "<pre>";
 print_r($content);
 echo "<pre>";
 endwhile;
 endif; ?>
```

Comment: You have misunderstood my question. I don't want to get the post link.
I want to extract link that contain in my post content.

Comment: Sorry, I am not checked your comment.Please check now my answer it working example

Answer (score 0):

Extracting URL within wordpress not easy part to extract. Why to more efforts if there are plugins available.

Install the following plugins and export them in CSV

https://wordpress.org/plugins/export-all-urls/